# How to specify the network configuration in the preseed file for connecting to a Wireless network?

Tags: ubuntu-server

I have been attempting ubuntu's unattended installation with the help of Kickstarter and a preseed file.
While everything succeeds in the installation,connection to the wireless interface fails.Is there anything else that needs to be specified for the network part to work?

```
 d-i netcfg/choose_interface select someInterface
 d-i netcfg/enable boolean true
 d-i netcfg/wireless_essid string someSSID
 d-i netcfg/wireless_essid_again string someSSID
 d-i netcfg/wireless_security_type select wpa
 d-i netcfg/wireless_wpa string someKey
```

Answer (score -1):

I was able to make it work with these settings:

```
# which chipset?
platform=AMD64

# Install OS instead of: upgrade
install

# Predetermine several required settings for wifi, misc.
preseed netcfg/choose_interface select wlan0
preseed netcfg/wireless_show_essids select manual
preseed netcfg/wireless_essid string WPA_ESSID
preseed netcfg/wireless_essid_again string WPA_ESSID
preseed netcfg/wireless_security_type select wpa
preseed netcfg/wireless_wpa string WPA_PASS
```